# Jquery resizable plugin, set minWidth on resize to width of child

Tags: jquery, resizable, css

How to dynamically set `minWidth` of a parent div depending on the right position of a child div.

My first hypothesis was:

```
$('#cell_'+cell).resizable({
    handles: "n, e, s, w, ne, nw, se, sw",
    containment: "parent",
    minWidth: getMaxWidthChilds(cell),
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        resi(cell, ui);
        subresize(cell);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        resi(cell, ui);
        subresize(cell);
    }
})
```

The child div is resizable and draggable so after the change of the position of the child, the `minWidth` of the parent div do not change.

Comment: Can you include the code for `getmaxWidthChilds(...)`? (Assuming that's possibly where the problem could be). You might also want to include the other functions, `resi(...)` and `subresize(...)`. Also, do realize that even though `minWidth` is "assigned" by a function, it is assigned **only once**, and `minWidth` is **never** updated again through the code you've posted.

Comment: getmaxWidthChilds(...) only gives the highest right position of the child div (left + whidth) and works great. resi(...) and subresize(...) are irrelevant for this case; 1st only shows the x,y position of the current div and subresize(...) auto-resize certain divs inside of this.

Comment: You are right, minWidth is assigned only once and never updated again and that is the problem. I can include $(this).resizable( "option", "minWidth", getMaxWidth(cell) ); in resize and stop properties but it is not solution. when the parent is at child's right limit and move child only allows me to re-size parent first to right then left to the new right position of child.

Comment: Do you think you can create the same scenario over at [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)? This will help us better understand what's going on, and troubleshoot it easier.

Comment: Got it... The minWidth property of parent div should be updated when resize or move child divs. I will try to post the solution for this problem as I think it will help in future.

Comment: Great, glad you found a solution!